# Getting a debugger break when directing my AppShell.xaml to a view I made

Tags: c#, maui

In my AppShell.xaml I have this view routed:

```
<Tab Title="signout">
    <ShellContent
         Title="SignOut"
         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SignOut}"
         Route="signout" />
 </Tab>
```

And this is the contents of my AppShell.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{

    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    /*  Routing.RegisterRoute("login", typeof(LoginPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("signup", typeof(SignUp));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("main", typeof(MainPage));*/
        Routing.RegisterRoute("signout", typeof(SignOut));
    }
}
```

The reason I have every registered rout commented out besides the signout view is because for some reason only my MainPage rout (a ContentPage not a ContentView) compiles correctly. All of my views crash on compile, directing me to this debugger break:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)         
      global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();  };
#endif
```

This is strange because the signout view only has the default contents:

SignOut.Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MUSignin.Views.SignOut">
   <VerticalStackLayout>
       <Label 
           Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
  </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

SignOutXaml.cs:

```
public partial class SignOut : ContentView
{
    public SignOut()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I read that this could happen when the debugger does not know what is wrong with the xaml or if there are nulls being passed but since I am using default xaml and am not passing nulls, what could be causing this break? Am I routing wrongly in the AppShell.xaml.cs?

Comment: What information is in the exception? (The e argument passed to the unhandled exception listener).

Comment: If it breaks, there will be an exception object passed.  This is basic c#

Comment: I am new to c# sorry for the misunderstanding. It looks like "{Microsoft.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}" is being passed as the exception with "Unable to cast object of type 'MUSignin.Views.SignOut' to type 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Page'." as the message.

Comment: There's your answer.  You can look at the stack trace of the exception object to see where the root cause of the exception is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot navigate to **ContentView**s, you can only navigate to **ContentPage**s.
Change this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MUSignin.Views.SignOut">
   
</ContentView>
```

to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MUSignin.Views.SignOut">
   
</ContentPage>
```

And this:

```cs
public partial class SignOut : ContentView
{
    public SignOut()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

to this:

```cs
public partial class SignOut : ContentPage
{
    public SignOut()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then your navigation will start to work.

*ContentView*s are typically child elements of *ContentPage*s. They are not interchangeable terms.

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo to reproduce the issue. It worked well on my side. You can check the tabbar code and replace it.

Here is the code in the AppShell.xaml.

```
 <TabBar>
 <Tab Title="signout">
     <ShellContent
      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:SignOut}"
      Route="signout" />
 </Tab>
     <Tab Title="Home">
     <ShellContent
      Title="Home"
      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
      Route="MainPage" />
 </Tab>
     
</TabBar>
```

Comment: You probably used pages for the ContentTemplate of the Tabs, the OP uses ContentViews, which cannot work.